# A Windows texteditor which supports transparent editing of gpg encrypted data

Tags: windows, text-editors, gnupg

Since I discovered [gnupg.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=661) I've really started using [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/) encryption on daily bases. This addon takes care of decryption when you open the file (asking for your keys pass phrase) and re-encrypts with modifications when the file is saved. Is there a text editor on windows (I'm using notepad++ right now) which have similar functionality?

Answer (score 2):

and why do you stop using vim? i mean, there are binaries of '[gpg](ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/gnupg-w32cli-1.4.10b.exe)' ready for windows, there is '[vim](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/)' ready for windows .. what stops you?

Comment: why link to code.google.com when Windows gVim is available [from vim.org's download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)?  (tho the answer might well be "64-bit", i'm not sure.)

Comment: @quack: because bram publishes up-to-date binaries (current most patch level) at that place... AND the 64bit version as well.

Comment: Actually I think gVim feels a bit out of place on a Windows. While I love vim and use it all the time for everything in console mode I prefer texteditors as UltraEdit and Notepad++ on Windows. Now I'm just waiting for the Emacs:ians to reply that Emacs are also on Win and have scripts with the same functionality :D I already now there is ;)

Comment: and (as crazy the emacsians are :)) right they are. why does vim feels unnatural on windows?

Answer (score -1):

Gpg4win is what you want, nice and simple

Comment: The OP is looking for a text editor that integrates with GPG. Does Gpg4win include a text editor?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide at least a link and, if possible, provide some additional information about the software itself such as what features it has and why it would be useful to the person who asked the question.